# How to link two different models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to learning Django and I am working on a page that just displays a users profile and reviews written for that user (both in different models).

The part that I'm a little unsure of is how to link different tables or models.  What I'm trying to do is extremely basic.  Pretty much as soon as you click on the name of a user, it goes to a profile page which also displays all of that users reviews on the bottom.  I'm wondering if I can use a variable in place of 'name=ben' and change it to something like 'name=user_you_clicked_on'.

Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense and maybe I can be pointed in the right direction.  I was told to try using a foreign key, but I'm not sure that's what I'm trying to do.

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

def index(request):
    profile_info = User.objects.filter(name=‘ben’)
    context = {‘profile_info’: profile_info}    
    latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.filter(name=‘ben').order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {‘profile_info’: profile_info, 'latest_reviews': latest_reviews}
    return render(request, 'randomtemplate.html', context)
```

Comment: Have you worked through the Django tutorial? This kind of relationship between models is something it covers pretty well. Generally you would indeed use a foreign key rather than a name, and capture it from the URL. It looks like you're storing the name of the user as a field on the `UserReview` model - that's a bad idea, violating standard database normalization guidelines as well as making this kind of thing harder.

Comment: What you probably want to do is add a foreign key relation that links any number of UserReview rows to a User row. See for an explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: By the way, you don't have to use the foreign key to look up the user reviews, you can use a syntax like this: `UserReview.objects.filter(user__name='ben')`. That is assuming you have set up a foreign key relation where the UserReview model class has a "user" attribute that references the User instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass username in the URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters) (ID would better but let's not overcomplicate this):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/', 'index'),
)
```

Then your view could look like this:

```
def index(request, username):
    profile_info = User.objects.filter(name=username)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you still want to 'connect' two tables. In models.py I would write:

```
   from django import models

   class User(models.Modle):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      #add more fields here

   class UserReview(models.Model):
      user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
      #add more fields here
```

This will create two tables in your db (User and UserReview) where Userreview is connected to User via a foreign key(one user(id) -> many reviews(user_id1; user_id1; user_id2 etc.)). By default this foreign key is the auto-generated id field of User table (by default id fields, which are also primary keys in this example, are auto-generated for each table, unless specified otherwise).

I hope it helps